# Create Rails Application with .rhtml file as start up page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an application where they have used **index.rhtml** in the main folder as start up page.

So how can I do this on my own using Ruby on rails i.e., How to create rails application with rhtml page as start up file.

Please post links if any for reference.

Thanks,
Kumar Raja Donthamsetti.

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete public.html
2. Add 'map.root :controller => "foo"' to routes.rb
3. and then of course create the controller foo with the action index.